# RPGs that only require 2 people

Tags: game-recommendation

Anyone know a good table top rpg that can be enjoyed with only 2 people? I'm researching couples things to do with my fiance for valentines day and we're both big rpg fans. (Ideally has a fantastical basis like Scion or Deadlands)

Comment: Game recommendations have become off-topic as of last year, which is why I've closed this question. **However**, we still have old questions about recommendations for games of this type hanging around in the [[tag:one-on-one]] tag. You can browse our archive of answered questions about such recommendations by [combining the two tags in a search, like this](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bone-on-one%5D+%5Bgame-recommendation%5D+answers%3A1). Cheers!